# jQuery DataTables Show and hide details feature using MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Is there a simple and clear example that shows how to use show/hide details about particular record feature of dataTables jQuery plug-in with MVC? If you have implemented this stuff and may share it with me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189621/Creating-an-expandable-master-details-table-jQuery) shows the implementation in details, have look at it

Comment: My answer incorporates @Aminul's reference.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look to the sample pages of DataTables:

- http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html
- http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: This helps none as I have looked at these pages, and they haven't given me (much) direction in how to implement using asp.net mvc.

Comment: What part are you having problems with? Do you have the datatable working?

Comment: @markpsmith Implementing the row details by using JSON to populate the data.